# Updating agent pools in release and build definitions using the azure devops API in C#

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We're facing a large-scale migration of our Azure Devops environment to Azure. This also means all (classic) release definitions and build definitions have to be updated with the new agent pools after the migration is done. Trouble is we have (a lot) a lot of them and updating all of them manually would be quite a job.

Is it possible to accomplish this with the Azure Devops REST API? And if yes, how (in C#)? I'm thinking of something like:

- List all build / release definitions (with filtering I guess, all of them at once would be too much)
- Loop through the definitions and then through all agent jobs (for build definitions) and/or all stages and then agent jobs inside the stages (for release definitions)
- Update all agent jobs with the new agent pools (based on the current one)
- Save with comment?

Would this be possible in C# with API REST calls (or .NET client libraries)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Rest API for [update build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) and [update release definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).

So, you need to first of all get the [build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) & [release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) definitions list, then loop them and update the pool.

You can use Rest API with every language you want. if you want C# you can use the [Azure DevOps .NET client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thanks! After some trouble I managed to update the release definitions with the .NET client libraries. Biggest problem was finding the agent pool matching the one configured in the release definition. In the Azure DevOps GUI it seems an agent pool is linked, but it actually is an agent queue that is linked (id's of both are different, agent queue has a 1-1 relation with agent pool luckily). Second problem was updating the QueueId, because it is really well hidden (unlike other properties) en can only be get/set when casting a resulting object. I will post the code in an update above soon.